# How can i load other content from a different html page on the same page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this main page with several buttons ont it.
I wonder how i can chance the content of a DIV with content on a different html page by clicking on the button.
any tips would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a div where you want your content to go to.

```
<div id="result"></div>    
<a href="#" id="other">Click Here</a>
```

Then using jQuery ajax `.load()` function you can get the data on another page and send the html to the div.

```
$(function() {    
   $("#other").click(function() {
       $('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
   });   
});
```

In this case when the user clicks the link, all the html from 'ajax/test.html' will be sent to the div with the id result.

Comment: Pretty sure Dennis wants the content of a `div` on that other page. Though he may want to *put* it in a `div`, also. He also wanted it in response to a button click, rather than when the page loads.

Comment: is there any way to link the button with that function?

Comment: Here is some code from the page with the buttons:
<div id="Menubalk"> // the div containing the buttons
<button id= BTNmessages>Messages</button> 
<div id="content"> content needs to come here </div>
// when you click this button the content of a different html page (named MessagePage.html) needs to be loaded into the "content" div.

so is it possible to implement the code you have given for this problem? because i cant seem to get it to work, or im over seeing something small.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow! People can be a little harsh here if you don't get comfy with the FAQ. You're going to want to always:

1. Tell us what you've tried
2. Show us your code

If you do those things, you'll find some amazing help here (despite already being downvoted ;).

To answer your question, you'll need to monitor clicks on your navigation element and load the page on click. You'll also want to ensure you *stop the button's default action*. All that can be achieved like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#target").click(function(e) {
    $('#result').load('file.html');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Where `#target` is your specific button,  `#result` is where your file.html loads to (on the current page), and `e.preventDefault()` stops your button from doing what it otherwise would (most people refer to this as hijacking).